# Is there a list of human rights organizations monitoring the current use of force by police in the US?

Tags: united-states, human-rights, police, media

During the law enforcing in the US, more press attacks happen:

- DW group [shot at](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NN8ISwuiX68) Minnesota
- CNN reporter was [arrested](https://www.washingtonpost.com/media/2020/05/29/omar-jimenez-cnn-minneapolis/)
- Reuters crew [hit](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-minneapolis-police-protest-update/reuters-cameraman-hit-by-rubber-bullets-as-police-disperse-protesters-idUSKBN237050) with rubber bullets

According to that obvious excessive use of force, are there any Human Rights organizations, who are monitoring use of force by regime forces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the biggest is Amnesty International. https://www.amnestyusa.org/

They do in-depth analysis of police brutality around the world. Both by reacting to current events but also by writing reports of systematic misuse of power over time.

Personally I wouldn't expect them to change much in most countries. Politicians most often disagree with their conclusions because everything happens based on the rulings of the same politicians.